# possible application servers for a chess game (android+web)

Tags: android, web-services, backend

I'm making a chess game,playable from both, an android device as well as a web browser.I will take input from user in a UI, & processing of that input-updating gamestate should happen at backend/application server.The response from server goes back to UI which displays the new gamestate.

Now my question is, what are possible options for application server I can explore to actually do this ?I'm not asking which is best or likewise....I just want to know what application servers are there which I can use to make my game.

I've made a similar application in netbeans using glassfish,but this time, I want an android device to be able to communicate with server too, so I'm confused how to approach this.

I've already tried google play services,but additional data about player,his statistics,etc needs to be stored client side,which I dont want.

Please suggest some alternatives.

Comment: Last alternative would be to use different servers for both platform,but a common database between them.Although I dont know how concurrency & other issues will be handled.

Comment: couldnt you use something like heroku , or just any old box with an ip or am i missing something

Comment: you haven't specified which technology you want in back-end .net, php, linux

Comment: Backend with Java.
@brendosthoughts,yes there are many others.However,I dont have android experience.Thats why Im asking this question so that any backend services that are difficult to use with android, can be filtered out...

Comment: ahhh okay , I would probably go with what you most familiar with i have used php , but rails would be a good option or node.js if you need some sort of very rapid talk with your end users

Comment: as a first time ap its easiest to think of development as using android(java +sdk) instead of html,css,javascript so whatever backend your most familiar with and like to use should be the one you use (at least for first app) as your likely not going to get into any of the real differences between mobile and web, rather you just need bts across the wire